# How to create a csv file from a list of pandas DataFrames?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I would like to create a csv file from a list of pandas dataframes. My data maintains all of the same column names besides for 1 column which is swapped each time. The following is what my list looks like based on the index of the list:

```
index 0:

height weight age isFunny
  4      2    21     0

index 1:

height weight age isCool
  10     30   81    34

index 2:

height weight age isDumb
  4      2    34     10

index 3:

height weight age isTalker
  4      12   25     3
```

I thought that the best way to save this data was in a list of pandas dataframes but if there is a better alternative, then please suggest any.

Comment: What do you want the CSV to look like?

Comment: Something that clearly depicts the information above. I would like to maintain the objects at each index so that I could easily identify associated information.

Comment: Are these all the same samples in different dataframes that you'd like to merge into one file or does each dataframe have separate samples that are also measured differently?

Comment: All of them maintain the exact same column names besides for the last column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use reduce to create a single dataframe and save it to a csv.

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame([[4,2,21,0]],columns='height weight age isFunny'.split())
df_2 = pd.DataFrame([[10,30,81,35]],columns='height weight age isCool'.split())
df_3 = pd.DataFrame([[4,2,34,10]],columns='height weight age isDumb'.split())
df_4 = pd.DataFrame([[4,12,25,3]],columns='height weight age isTalker'.split())
l = [df_1, df_2, df_3, df_4]

from functools import reduce
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: x.append(y), l)

   age  height  isCool  isDumb  isFunny  isTalker  weight
0   21       4     NaN     NaN      0.0       NaN       2
1   81      10    35.0     NaN      NaN       NaN      30
2   34       4     NaN    10.0      NaN       NaN       2
3   25       4     NaN     NaN      NaN       3.0      12
```

Comment: This isn't what I want though. If I wanted this, all you would do is convert the list of dataframes back to a pandas.core.series.Series then pass the list name in to cast the entire list as a pandas dataframe. Simply put you can do: pd.DataFrame(myDF) and you'll achieve the same outcome. But, I don't want that. I want to keep my separate dataframes all held together in a single csv.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `myDF` is your list of DataFrames you can serialize it like this:

```
import pickle
pickle.dump(myDF, "my_file.pickle")
```

Then you can load it whenever with this:

```
import pickle
myDF = pickle.load("my_file.pickle")
```

What you want to do can technically be done with a CSV file but it would be unwise to have a CSV with multiple headers. You could do that, though:

```
my_file_name = "my_file.csv"
[df.to_csv(my_file_name, mode="a+", index=False) for df in myDF]
```

Don't do this. This is dumb.

Based on your additional context, I would suggest doing this (which is similar in concept to the other answer):

```
melted_df = pd.concat([df.melt(id_vars = ['height', 'weight', 'age']) for df in myDF])
melted_df.to_csv("my_file.csv")
```

You may wish to unroll the MultiIndex into columns again.

Comment: Okay, if you don't recommend this then what's the best alternative.

Comment: Save separate data sets into separate CSV files or serialize your list into a pickled object file. Cramming these dataframes into one CSV file for no reason makes no sense.

Comment: Well I am working with patient data and analyzing different variables of hundreds of patients. We maintain variables that will always be present like demographics, but there are also variables that are swapped out. So, if you have any alternative ideas, I would gladly opt to use them.

Comment: Try melting them. That's pretty much the best answer because you can pack them into a single dataframe and CSV file.

Comment: What does it mean to melt them, can you share some code and documentation please.

Comment: It's in the answer.

Comment: I see that id_vars has a predefined label of column headers but like I was saying before, the issue that the final column changes each time. How would I handle that?

Comment: The column that changes gets melted into a column name (that goes into a `variable` column) and a column value (that goes into a `value` column). You then have a dataframe which has the same headers and has all your information. You may think of this as a key -> value type table which also has the other data from your non-changing columns.